# Colour Change in Richedit Windowless operation

Tags: c++, highlighting, richedit

I am trying to achieve something similar to domain highlighting. I want part of my text in rich edit box to to be of different colour like we have in domain highlighting feature of IE.

Issue :
I know we have to first use `EM_EXSETSEL` to select the required text and then apply `EM_SETCHARFORMAT`.

`EM_EXSETSEL` perform the required operation and required text get selected properly.
However , when i execute the `EM_SETCHARFORMAT` , no change happens in the selected text.

Window is created using RICHEDIT_CLASS .

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this (to set bold, red text on the current selection):

```
   // Set up the CHARFORMAT structure
   CHARFORMAT cfm;
   cfm.cbSize = sizeof(cfm);    // Don't forget this!

   // Get char format
   ::SendMessage(hWnd, EM_GETCHARFORMAT, SCF_SELECTION, (LPARAM)&cfm);

   // Set the new effects
   cfm.dwEffects   = CFE_BOLD;
   cfm.crTextColor = RGB(255,0,0);
   cfm.dwMask      = CFM_BOLD | CFM_COLOR;

   // Set the new format
   ::SendMessage(hWnd, EM_SETCHARFORMAT, SCF_SELECTION, (LPARAM)&cfm);
```

where hWnd is the window handle of the Rich Edit control.

If not... then post some code, so we can see where you might be going wrong...

Comment: I dont have access to code right now..but i can share the details.... As i listed that i required editing for Windowless operation ...so i am using Txsendmessage instead...
Could you please suggest the reason to use EM_GETCHARFORMAT before SET call...
my code is something like this 
   cfm.dwEffects   = 0;
   cfm.crTextColor = RGB(255,0,0);
   cfm.dwMask      = FM_COLOR;

   // Set the new format
   ::SendMessage(hWnd, EM_SETCHARFORMAT, SCF_SELECTION, (LPARAM)&cfm);


do we need to exectue any more message to view the changed text color..

Comment: No reason to use EM_GETCHARFORMAT first, this is cribbed from some of my code where I read the charformat, then checked to see if the proposed format was actually changing it to save time otherwise.  The only thing I can think of is that it's probably a good idea to `memset(&cfm, 0, sizeof(cfm));` first, and you need to set the size: 
`cfm.cbSize = sizeof(cfm);` (if Windows doesn't recognize the size, because it's not initialized, it might just ignore you)

Comment: sorry i missed that thing....this is part of my code....
Also , i am using charformat2 structure instead of charformat

Comment: Never used windowless rich edit controls or TxSendMessage, sorry... not sure I can help more...